# How to get raw ethereum transaction hash

Tags: transactions, raw-transaction

I searched around for an answer to this question, however couldn't find one.
So let's assume we've a **raw** ethereum transaction and before broadcasting we'd like to know the transaction hash. Is it possible to find out the hash before it's being broadcasted (i.e. via eth_sendRawTransaction RPC method).

For instance for **raw transaction hex**:

```
0xf86c258502540be40083035b609482e041e84074fc5f5947d4d27e3c44f824b7a1a187b1a2bc2ec500008078a04a7db627266fa9a4116e3f6b33f5d245db40983234eb356261f36808909d2848a0166fa098a2ce3bda87af6000ed0083e3bf7cc31c6686b670bd85cbc6da2d6e85
```

I get this transaction:
https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x58e5a0fc7fbc849eddc100d44e86276168a8c7baaa5604e44ba6f5eb8ba1b7eb

**Is it possible to decode raw transaction so that this hash is known before hand?** 
Note that I am storing private keys outside of applications such as **geth/parity.**

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong: after mining transaction you receive the same transaction hash as after getting keccak256 hash from raw tx? My tests show that keccak256 hash of raw signed tx is NOT equal to transactionHash generated by ethereum while mining. I would appreciate if somebody could tell me how exactly transactionHashes are generated as there is no iformation available even in yellow paper of ethereum.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, so asked it a couple of minutes too soon. As the name implies it's a hash, hash of what? Hash of your **raw hex** in example:

```
0xf86c258502540be40083035b609482e041e84074fc5f5947d4d27e3c44f824b7a1a187b1a2bc2ec500008078a04a7db627266fa9a4116e3f6b33f5d245db40983234eb356261f36808909d2848a0166fa098a2ce3bda87af6000ed0083e3bf7cc31c6686b670bd85cbc6da2d6e85
```

Hashed using **keccak256** (for instance can be found here: https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-web3-module#web3_sha3): and the result as expected is:

```
0x58e5a0fc7fbc849eddc100d44e86276168a8c7baaa5604e44ba6f5eb8ba1b7eb
```

So ended up being a short rhetorical question. However if someone has similar question... hope this helps!

Comment: It is not a stupid question. In Bitcoin, a hash of the transaction is presented in the opposite endianness so even though you may think that there is only one way to represent a hash as a string, that is not the case.

Comment: Is this a hash of the signed transaction or the unsigned transaction? For the purposes of validating transaction data, can I derive a transaction hash just from the transaction data itself without knowledge of the private key?

Comment: This is hash from the signed raw hex. I don't imagine you could derive it from unsigned data, since unsigned transaction has different "raw" representation and as such the hash of this would be also different than the hash of signed hex.

Comment: No this is unsigned raw hex. The transaction must be hashed before it is signed. Geth verifies the transaction validity by hashing the txn message and applying ecrecover to the hash and hash signature. Raw transactions don't get signed as it is inefficient to do so.