# How do I predict my transaction hash before putting through a transaction?

Tags: transactions, hash

I'm trying to figure out how to get the transaction hash for some transactions. I don't have the hashes in my data; all I have is approximate time (to the minute), size, and token. I think I can get the raw transaction hex.  I want to get the transaction hash. I looked at this post: [How to get raw ethereum transaction hash](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31285/how-to-get-raw-ethereum-transaction-hash) but when I hashed the raw hex myself I didn't get the same hash as the poster, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I hashed it with and without the '0x' before thinking that that was the problem, but it wasn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hashed the raw hex (`f86c258502540be40083035b609482e041e84074fc5f5947d4d27e3c44f824b7a1a187b1a2bc2ec500008078a04a7db627266fa9a4116e3f6b33f5d245db40983234eb356261f36808909d2848a0166fa098a2ce3bda87af6000ed0083e3bf7cc31c6686b670bd85cbc6da2d6e85`) from your link using Keccak256 and got `58e5a0fc7fbc849eddc100d44e86276168a8c7baaa5604e44ba6f5eb8ba1b7eb`, same as that of the poster. Note: You have to rid the `0x` of the raw hex before hashing it.

See: https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html

Comment: I don't get that.  When I plug in the same number, I get the hash "94bc16b7b18d195bd5d5938d16acba217aa27f0d4488e6bdb7e34745d838c484".  I took out the 0x.

Comment: You need to change the input type to "Hex", not "Text", before hashing.

Comment: Yep, that did it!